# Should I use "searching" or "to search" when talking about a tip?

Tags: word-usage

I asked a question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343773/706203) with title "Is it possible to search some keywords in title only?"

Another similar question used the title "Searching for words in question titles"

Is my version more grammatical and idiomatic than the other? In other words, should I use "searching" or "to search"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary, the "searching" in an adjective which should be used before a noun, like searching questions. therefore, searching for is incorrect, it should be "a search for"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess "a search for" is emphasizing "this action is a search", while what I was trying to do is how to search, right?

Comment: "a search for" is an attempt to find sth and "searching" is trying to find out the truth. your sentence is completely correct "It is possible to search", meaning "one can find"